# How to open new tab with running specific command in Powershell (Windows Terminal)?

Tags: windows-terminal

What I want is to open a new tab having Powershell and running a specific command (in my case "npm run local").

I was expecting this will work,

`wt -w 0 -p "Windows Powershell" npm run local`

But, it gives an error,

`` [error 0x80070002 when launching `npm run local'] ``

---

Is it possible and how?

*Note: I have done a lot of research and also read the official documentation, but I was not able to find a way.

Comment: I've been using Windows Terminal for a couple of years and didn't know about `wt`. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the best/recommended solution from **Windows Terminal developers**.

[Answer on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/9895#issuecomment-823199630)

> For both Command Prompt and Powershell.
>
> `wt --window 0 -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run local"`

> Only for Powershell.
>
> `wt --window 0 -p "Windows Powershell" -d "$pwd" powershell -noExit "npm run local"`

---

The best use of this feature while running commands for development, in my case

For Powershell

```
wt --window 0 -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run startMongo"`;  split-pane --horizontal -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run gulp-watch"`;  new-tab -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run local"
```

For Command Prompt

```
wt --window 0 -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run startMongo";  split-pane --horizontal -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run gulp-watch";  new-tab -p "Windows Powershell" -d . powershell -noExit "npm run local"
```

Comment: Is the `-d .` really required?  It seems that it uses the current working directory by default, but I just tried with an `npm init` (which executed in the current directory) rather than `npm run local`.

Comment: Note that for anyone using PowerShell Core, it seems that you will need the `-c` flag, as in `pwsh -c -NoExit "npm run local"`.  I missed that in my original answer.

Comment: I see I was wrong on PowerShell not being able to parse the `.cmd` from the command line.  That said, since it's a `.cmd` file anyway, wouldn't it be more "proper" (or perhaps "efficient", although efficiency isn't really a goal here) to pass it directly to `cmd.exe`.  Passing it to `powershell.exe` just invokes PowerShell, which in turn invokes CMD anyway.  Can't you just cut out the middleman?

Comment: Yes, you are right I can cut the middleman by directly parsing to cmd.exe. Another thing, I tried without `-d .` option, but it is not executed in current directory (It is executed in my user directory i.e. `C:\Users\Rajan`). I guess you just excuted `npm init` which created a new project in your user directory. Try to create a project on Desktop & see if it's working.

Comment: Yes, you're right, too, of course!  I started in ``C:\``, changed to `$env:userprofile`, and naively assumed that because it created it in the userprofile directory, it was using the current directory.  Of course, that was a bad assumption.  Any other directory fails without the `-d .`, as you said.

Comment: Also found that, if you add the extension (`npm.cmd`), it runs with your original "just the profile" style command.  But that doesn't work if you want to keep the tab open when the process ends.

Comment: Just adding a suggestion here.  I prefer using the pwsh.exe command and the parameters are just slightly different.

I used this

```wt --window 0 -d D:\ABC123\  -p "PowerShell" pwsh -noExit -Command "npm start"```

Answer (score 6):

Running `Get-Command npm` shows that `npm` is actually `npm.cmd`, so a CMD interpreted script, not PowerShell.  When run directly at the command-line, PowerShell is okay with leaving the extension off, but when passed through a Windows Terminal profile, the extension appears to be required:

```
wt -w 0 -d . -p "Windows PowerShell" npm.cmd init
wt -w 0 -d . -p "Command Prompt" npm.cmd init
```

(Edit:  `-d .` added per your comment.  Without that, as you pointed out, it will always default to the `%userprofile%` directory).

That said, it seems from your comment that your use-case is to keep the tab open after the process completes.  In that case ...

```
wt -w 0 -d . -p "Windows PowerShell" cmd /k npm run local
wt -w 0 -d . -p "Command Prompt" cmd /k npm run local
```

Comment: `wt -w 0 -p "Windows PowerShell" -d . cmd /k npm run local` is working.